# Commented out VirtualHost in Apache config and restarted - can still access site

Tags: apache-2.2

I commented out a VirtualHost configuration in Apache. After reloading/restarting Apache, I can still access the site. Does Apache cache the VirtualHost configurations?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not cache - but it'll always map a request to a `<VirtualHost>`.

Check the output of `apache2ctl -S` - it will tell you what's configured and what the defaults are.  If you're certain that you're getting content from the disabled vhost (and not the default on that port, instead), then the service didn't restart correctly.

Comment: The site is not showing up when running apache2ctl. I even tried accessing the site form a computer that has never accessed the site (so it's not a caching issue, I don't think).

Comment: Anything else I can check. I must be totally missing something. I feel like I've commented out a vhost a million times and never seen this. I also commented out 5 other sites and they are still accessible as well. I've restarted/reloaded multiple times.

Comment: Completely stop Apache, and then use ps to double check that it is actually stopped?  Perhaps the restart script is broken?